# How to set Alert when I click more than 5 numbers?

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a page with a number pad at top and text input at the bottom! whenever press the buttons on Numpad it shows below !after clicking more the 5 number it shows alert How it is possible?

I tried by using a length

```
                                 maxLength={5}
                                 onChangeText={()=>{

                                  let Id = this.state.id.toString()
                                  if(Id.length > 5 ){
                                Alert.alert('Please Enter 5 Digit Id number ')
                                  }

                                }}


                                >{this.state.id}
                                </TextInput>
```

Comment: Why are you converting to a string `let Id = this.state.id.toString()`?

Comment: Can you explain better what's the problem here? I don't get what your problem is

Comment: Actually In my screen Numpad is there !with 1 to 9 number each button is a touchable highlight!when press any button the following number is shown in below text input! when I click more than 5 numbers  it shows Alert

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming it is a phone pad type consisting 0-9 digits.
So on every button/Touchable there will be a onPress handler as

```
MAX_LENGTH=5;
addNumber=(number)=>{
   const {listOfNumbers}=this.state;
   if(listOfNumbers.length===MAX_LENGTH){
     Alert.alert('5 numbers only');
   }else{
     this.setState({
      listOfNumbers:[...listOfNumbers,number]
     });
   }
}

<Touchable onPress={e=>this.addNumberToList(<some number between 0,9>)}>
   ....
</Touchable>
```